# How can I configure play framework to start before log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2, playframework-2.5

In my project, I need to read password from `application.conf` in play and pass it to `ConnectionFactory` class to make `DatabaseConnection` for JDBC appender in log4j2.

But my problem is that, log4j starts and goes to `ConnectionFactory` class **before play has started** and `play.configuration()` has loaded. Therefore `configuration.getString("password")` is not recognize yet.

Does anyone has suggestion, how to force play to start before log4j2? In other word, how to make log4j2 depend on play starup?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the Play framework is doing any logging then you must start Log4j2 before Play. Otherwise, the first call Play makes to obtain a Logger will cause Log4j2 to initialize.

I would suggest that you write a custom Lookup that can locate the application.conf and extract the password from it.